# Creating App wide and user specific databases with PouchDB

Tags: ionic2, pouchdb

Is it possible to create databases with PouchDB that are available to all users of the App and have databases as well that are tied to specific users?

My simple App is essentially as follows:

- The App is for a micro brewery. It contains a list of the brewery's currently available beers. This is the database that needs to be available to all App users
- Every user can create a bookmarked list of beers they want to drink and beers they have tried. This is the database that needs to be specific to each user.
- If a user is logged in to the App with admin privileges they will be able to add/remove beers to/from the database of beers that is available to all users.

I am using the SuperLogin Node.js server for user authentication and the App is implemented using the ionic 2 framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two (or as many as you like) databases with PouchDB, so yes, you can do what you want to do.

The " list of the brewery's currently available beers" database should be on a CouchDB server and PouchDB can access that when the user is online. You can sync that to a PouchDB in the user's web browser if you want but not provide them with any function to write to it.

The "list of beers they want to drink and beers they have tried" database can be in the users web browser only. If you want to let them store that online as well you need to make both a CouchDB user and a database for them.

Check out [pouchdb-authentication](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication) for more info and look into "Admins", "Members", and "Roles" there and in the CouchDB docs as well.